# Which rails controller should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rails-routing

In my app `Users` can `Like` `Programs`. Each of those is a model, `Like` is polymorphic.

At some point I will want to see all the `Users` that `Like` a `Program` or all `Programs` a `User Likes`.

Is it better to have a `likes` and `likers` controller action in the `users` and `programs` controller? Or should I have the `likes` controller as a nested resource with both a `users` and `programs` action (or an Index which checks which nested resource is being used)?

I realize all of these can work, but wasn't sure what was Rails best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure your app to have a `UsersController` with a `likes` member action which returns the `Program`s that user likes. And then have a `ProgramsController` with a `likers` member action, which gives the `User`s which like that program.

To simplify things further, you could also just include the user's likes in the `show` action, (and similarly, show the users who like a program in the program's `show` action), although you may end up fetching more information than is necessary in the `show` actions by doing it that way.

Comment: Is there an general rule of thumb when deciding these things? Like less controllers is better?

Comment: If you created a `LikesController`, its resource would be a "like", which it sounds like is the "join model" in your scenario. Your description made it seem like you either wanted to access "likes" organized by a particular user or by a particular program, so it makes more sense to present the likes as actions on the UsersController or ProgramsController.

Answer (score 1):

Restfully, you would have a LikesController and a 'create' action within it would take a user_id and a program_id.  It's likely the user will be logged in (and won't be passed in the URL), and it will make sense to create a Like, passing a program_id to a url that looks something like this:

```
POST /likes, :params => { :program_id => ___ }
```

You may want to show a list of Likes (index page), perhaps allowing users to edit and delete.  If this is the case, all your actions would be on the likes_controller.  Usually, it depends on your situation, but a restful design is usually the right place to start.

Comment: The like is done via AJAX. There are create and destroy actions, that part is working fine.

I would need Likes as a nested resource under both users and programs in order to keep the actions in the likes controller. It seems easier in the User and Program controllers...but it didn't feel very RESTful.

Comment: I see.  If you are looking for a list of programs, that would be on the index action in the ProgramsController.  It may be filtered by user_id and have a url like users/1/programs. But, it's also possible you really want likes users/1/likes.  If so, I'd simply add a method to filter the likes in the index action on the likes controller.  The last option I've used is to make controllers for the joins - UserLikesController and ProgramLikesController.  The only action would be index.  This is nice because you can subclass Likes and retain permissions before filters, etc.

Comment: Oooo, that's an interesting idea. I'll have to try that and see how that works.

Comment: Part of my dilemma is extensability. Right now I only have programs that can be liked, but I hope to extend that. Which makes it easier to just put it in the other controllers and ignore too many joins controllers or likes controller needing to be nested a million different ways.

Comment: You'll probably have urls that indicate the parent, they won't be 'polymorphic' at all, if that's the case, you can still do this and simply get likes based on the explicit object.  Another thought, you may be able to have a single controller that expects a likeable type and id that can be defined in routes.  So you have all the urls, but only one controller.